# Type 'CAMediaTimingFillMode' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'forwards'

Tags: ios

Type 'CAMediaTimingFillMode' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'forwards'

groupAnim.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards

Answer (score 19):

You can change your code with `groupAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards`.